# How to perform slide right using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I had a div class that generate a arrow >>. when that div is clicked I want to show the list of items which should slide from left to right and should wait for 20 secs. When clicked once again, it should slide left and disappear.

I'm trying it using `Jquery` but not working.
Please help me. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you add the code which is not working?

Comment: How is the jQuery code you wrote?

Comment: I havent started Yet, Please guide me

Comment: I havent wrote the code yet, Guide me plz

Comment: Ok, write the HTML code for a guide

Comment: I'm curious, how can code that hasn't been written yet not be working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
   $("#right").click(function(){
      $(".block").animate({"right": "+=50px"}, "slow");
    });
```

This code assumes an element with the class "block" inside a container element with an id of "right". The element with the class "block" will be the one which will slide to the right around 50px.

To help yourself try these tutorials:

http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-video-series/

Comment: Is this dependent on a plugin or an older version of JQuery? Copied verbatim but no effect :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {       
    $("#search-inline").click(function() {
        $(".window_box").toggle({"left": "+=250px"}, 3000);
    });
});
</script>

//click link
<a id="search-inline" title="Search"  href="#content" alt="Search"> Search </a>

//initially hide the div
<div class="window_box" style="display:none; width:500px; height:500px;"> 
//content 
</div>
```